# Is there a way to use elasticsearch to return only one hit per matched field?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

### NOTE: Updated to include NodeJS client details. See edits below.

I'm trying to avoid having to query ElasticSearch repeatedly to get the information I need.

Say I have a data set that consists of events in cities. Documents in the data set might look like this:

```
{
    city: 'Berlin',
    event: 'Dance party',
    date: '2017-04-15'
},
{
    city: 'Seattle',
    event: 'Wine tasting',
    date: '2017-04-18'
},
{
    city: 'Berlin',
    event: 'Dance party,
    date: '2017-04-21'
},
{
    city: 'Hong Kong',
    event: 'Theater',
    date: '2017-04-25'
}...
```

Now say the list of all tracked cities is known, and I need to get just the most recent event from each city. So I need to be able to feed into the query an array of city names, something along the lines of `['Berlin', 'Hong Kong', 'Seattle']` and get back only the bottom three events.

My current query can only accomplish this by running repeatedly with a size of 1, and doing an exact match on the city name, like so:

```
{
    size: 1,
    body: {
        sort: [
            {'date': {'order': 'desc'}}
        ],
        query: {
            'match_phrase': {'city': 'Berlin'}
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to write the script so I can pass the whole list of cities into one query and predictably get *only* the most recent entry for each city?

**Edit**

My new script looks like this:

```
{
    'query': {
        'match_all': {}
    },
    '_source': ['city', 'event', 'date'],
    'aggs': {
        'cities': {
            'terms': {
                'field': 'city',
                'size': 100
            },
            'aggs': {
                'top_cities': {
                    'top_hits': {
                        'size': 1,
                        '_source': 'event',
                        'sort': {
                            'date': 'desc'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This looks like it really should work. But I'm still missing tons of cities I know are in there, and one appears multiple times.

I'm running this in Node, with the elasticsearch-js package. The client executed this way:

```js
let client = new elasticSearch.Client(
    {
        "host": [
            "host1:9200",
            "host2:9200",
            "host3:9200"
        ]
    }
);
client.search(SEARCH_PARAMS)
    .then(function (resp) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
    });
```

Here is a (sanitized) version of the resulting JSON:

```
{
    "took": 77,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 42,
        "successful": 42,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 5685608,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [{
            "_index": "sanitized",
            "_type": "sanitized",
            "_id": "AVu489lVgqYk_9QxQb-U",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "event": "Dance party",
                "date": "2017-04-15",
                "city": "Berlin"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "sanitized",
            "_type": "sanitized",
            "_id": "AVu489lVgqYk_9QxQb-X",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "event": "Dance party",
                "date": "2017-04-15",
                "city": "Berlin"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "sanitized",
            "_type": "sanitized_variant_1",
            "_id": "AVu489lVgqYk_9QxQb-a",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "event": "Dance party",
                "date": "2017-04-29",
                "city": "Berlin"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "sanitized",
            "_type": "sanitized_variant_2",
            "_id": "AVu489lVgqYk_9QxQb-b",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "event": "Dance party",
                "date": "2017-04-29",
                "city": "Berlin"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "sanitized",
            "_type": "sanitized_variant_2",
            "_id": "AVu489lVgqYk_9QxQb-d",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "event": "Dance party",
                "date": "2017-04-29",
                "city": "Hong Kong"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "sanitized",
            "_type": "sanitized_variant_2",
            "_id": "AVu489lVgqYk_9QxQb-f",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "event": "Dance party",
                "date": "2017-04-29",
                "city": "Hong Kong"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "sanitized",
            "_type": "sanitized_variant_2",
            "_id": "AVu49AkKCe9swQD44WnN",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "event": "Dance party",
                "date": "2017-04-29",
                "city": "Seattle"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "sanitized",
            "_type": "sanitized_variant_2",
            "_id": "AVu49AkKCe9swQD44WnP",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "event": "Dance party",
                "date": "2017-04-29",
                "city": "New York"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "sanitized",
            "_type": "sanitized_variant_1",
            "_id": "AVu49AkKCe9swQD44WnY",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "event": "Dance party",
                "date": "2017-04-29",
                "city": "Berlin"
            }
        }, {
            "_index": "sanitized",
            "_type": "sanitized_variant_2",
            "_id": "AVu49AkKCe9swQD44Wnb",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "event": "Dance party",
                "date": "2017-04-29",
                "city": "Berlin"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

On closer inspection, the aggregations are not being added to the `resp` object for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to filtering the cities in the query, I suggest to use a `terms` aggregation on the city field and then a `top_hits` sub-aggregation to retrieve on the latest event per city:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "cities": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_events": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": "event",
            "sort": {
              "date": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This looked promising, but I'm getting far fewer documents returned than I expected, and what gets returned has several duplicates. Could the size of the array of "cities" have anything to do with it? There are about 70, and what I'm expecting back is one hit per city.

Comment: Then simply remove the query part. updated my answer

Comment: Getting closer, but still have one city appearing multiple times with different dates. Each record has other fields on it I don't care about. Even the "event" field could be excluded. I literally just want the name of the city and the date, without duplicate cities. Is there some way to explicitly tell ElasticSearch not to return a hit if a hit with that city name has already been returned? Oh, and thank you very much for your responses.

Comment: Since we're using a `terms` aggregation, I highly doubt that you're getting the same city multiple times. Unless they are not written the same way.

Comment: It's weird. It really looks like it shouldn't be doing that, but it is, and I guarantee the spelling is the same. I've updated the post with the current version of my script.

Comment: {
   "_index": "sanitized",
   "_type": "sanitized",
   "_id": "AVu489lVgqYk_9QxQb-U",
   "_score": 1,
   "_source": {
    "event": "Dance party",
    "date": "2017-04-15",
    "city": "Berlin"
   }
  }, {
   "_index": "sanitized",
   "_type": "sanitized",
   "_id": "AVu489lVgqYk_9QxQb-X",
   "_score": 1,
   "_source": {
    "event": "Dance party",
    "date": "2017-04-15",
    "city": "Berlin"
   }

Comment: I've sanitized that output some. Obviously, the real data isn't dance parties in Berlin.

Comment: Please update your question with the full response (not only hits), it's more legible than in comments

Comment: I've added a sanitized version of the full results. As you can see, it's much smaller than expected and contains duplicates.

Comment: You're looking at the hits instead of the aggregations :-) I've added `"size": 0` in the query. See my updated answer

Comment: How are you running your query? Make sure to use POST and not GET (especially if using the head plugin)!!

Comment: I'm actually running it through the elasticsearch-js Node package. And it's definitely not returning aggregations. I'll see if I can find out why. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Maybe update your question with the node.js code you're using and we'll figure out

Comment: Added. `SEARCH_PARAMS` is just the search parameters as a JavaScript object.

Comment: I've got it! I left out the `body` parameter, which is an elasticsearch-js requirement! It was in the original script, but somehow I lost it when I was trying to implement yours. Otherwise, you were spot on! +1.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html), passing all those cities, something like:

```
"query": {
    "terms": {
      "city": [
        "BERLIN",
        "RIO DE JANEIRO"
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "size": 3,
  "_source": "city",
  "sort": [
    {
      "date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```